# Rotate X Axis Labels of twoord.plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I am using the `twoord.plot` function in the [plotrix](http://cran.r-project.org/package=plotrix) package and need to rotate the X Axis tick labels 45 degrees. Anyone know how to do so?

Comment: If you post some example code it will be easier to help you.  See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/602276

Comment: @Ben Bolker : any reason this got the r-faq tag?

Comment: well, the solution to "how do I get rotated labels" is in the R FAQ ... or should the r-faq tag be reserved for "questions which are frequently asked on SO"?

Comment: @BenBolker : Ah yeah, you might have missed the discussion in the chat. It was indeed meant to be used for questions frequently asked on SO. So I'll remove it again, but if the question comes up again, it can always be added.

Comment: refer to this answer **https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2014-July/420223.html**,it may help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to suppress the usual labeling and put your desired labeling in with `text(..., srt=45)`. Since by default text only goes in the plot region, the `y` argument may need to be negative, and you will need to extend the plotting region by "lowering" the third argument to `usr`. This is all [described in the R-FAQ.](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-can-I-create-rotated-axis-labels_003f)

Comment: I tried your suggestion and unfortunately it didn't work. I took a look at the code for the `twoord.plot()` function and it sets many of these parameters in the function which appear to override my temporary global changes of `par()`. Any thoughts? I'm going to try making a custom version of the function which would contain the text rotation using `text(..., srt=45)` as you suggested.