# how do i get a 45 angle for the x axis labels in the following code

Tags: r, axis-labels

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotate X Axis Labels of twoord.plot in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079526/rotate-x-axis-labels-of-twoord-plot-in-r)

The following code runs fine. I wish to get the xlabels to be at 45 angle since they are long and i do not want to change there size (i need the whole name).

`mp <-    barplot(v,names.arg = c("Lung Lavage Fluid","Erythroleukemic Cell Line",
"Blood Plasma","T - Cell Cell Line","Liver Whole Cell","B - Lymphocytes",
"panc","prostate","Bladder Urine"),cex.names=0.65,col = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
main = val2,density = 50,angle = 45,xlab = "TISSUE",ylab = "EXPRESSION VALUE",
,border = "blue");`

palette(c('blue','green','red','pink','brown','coral','deepskyblue','yellow','yellowgreen'));

Comment: This is in the R-FAQ and it's already been asked and answered on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6079526/rotate-x-axis-labels-of-twoord-plot-in-r. I vote to close.

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, with base graphics, you can only ask for 0/90° orientation of labels on x- or y-axis (see the `las` parameter in `par()`). However, with [lattice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lattice/index.html) or [ggplot2](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/) you can do it.

Here is an example with `lattice::barchart()`:

```
tt <- table(sample(LETTERS[1:6], 100, rep=T))
library(lattice)
barchart(tt, horiz=F, 
         scales=list(x=list(rot=45, labels=paste("Fancy label", 1:6))))
```

[image: bar chart]

Replace `labels` with your own labels or if you already have a named table, leave it as is.

Comment: Using ggplot2, this can be done by adding `+ opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(angle =45)` to your plot